# Extract Mobile/Phone Number from a string in HIVE using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, hive

I have a string which is
"You can also connect with me on this number (+123) 456 789.

I have to extract the phone number and have to mask it with **phone number**

```
Select regexp_extract ('You can also connect with me on this number 99XXXXXXXX', '[0-9]+',0);
```

I was able to get the phone number But I don't really know how to regexp_replace it for masking it to ***Mobile number***

Also if possible what REGEX should I use if there are spaces in the phone number

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to extract phone number.

```
select regexp_extract( regexp_replace(col,'[^0-9]',''), '[0-9]{10}',0) phno,
regexp_replace(col,'[^0-9]','')
from (
select 'You can also connect with me on this number (+123) 456 7890.' as col union 
select 'reach me at +133 444 5678 anytime'
) rs
```

Once you have the valid 10 digit phone number, you can mask them like below. This will show the word 'phone number' else null.

```
select if(length(regexp_extract( regexp_replace(col,'[^0-9]',''), '[0-9]{10}',0))=10,'Phone number', null) phno_masked 
from (
select 'You can also connect with me on this number (+123) 456 7890.' as col union 
select 'reach me at +133 444 5678 anytime'
) rs
```

`regexp_replace(col,'[^0-9]','')` - this code will remove all characters except numbers.
regexp_extract - This will ensure the count of numbers are 10.

Pls note, if your data has other numbers, then it will be an issue. For example, if you have data like `reach me at 123 456 7890 after 10AM`. Kindly validate your data, identify pattern and use above sql.

Output screenshot of above sql is below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you but do you know like how would I mask it

Comment: Like it will not show the phone number instead it will show the string as *Phone Number *

Comment: updated the answer.